# R programming download.file() returning 403 Forbidden error

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

Been scraping a webpage previously and it is now returning a **403 Forbidden error**. When I visit the site manually through a browser I have no problems, however when I scrape the page now I get the error.

Code is:

```
url <- 'https://www.punters.com.au/form-guide/'
download.file(url, destfile = "webpage.html", quiet=TRUE)
html <- read_html("webpage.html")
```

Error is:

```
Error in download.file(url, destfile = "webpage.html", quiet = TRUE) : 
  cannot open URL 'https://www.punters.com.au/form-guide/'
In addition: Warning message:
In download.file(url, destfile = "webpage.html", quiet = TRUE) :
  cannot open URL 'https://www.punters.com.au/form-guide/': HTTP status was '403 Forbidden'
```

I've looked at the documentation and tried finding an answer online but had no luck so far. Any suggestions how I can circumvent this?

Comment: It looks to me like the domain doesn’t want you scraping its content. It is their right…

Answer (score 5):

Looks like they added **user-agent** validation. You need to add user-agent and it works.
If you do not put user-agent of some browser, the site thinks that you are bot and block you. Here you have some python code.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

baseurl = "https://www.punters.com.au/form-guide/"
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"}
page = requests.get(baseurl, headers=headers).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
title = soup.find("div", class_="short_title")
print("Title: " +title.text)
```

**Request in R with user-agent:**

```
require(httr)

headers = c(
  `user-agent` = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.5005.61 Safari/537.36'
)

res <- httr::GET(url = 'https://www.punters.com.au/form-guide/', httr::add_headers(.headers=headers))
```

Comment: Thanks for the response MeT but this is for R-programming, not Python! Any idea how to add the agent in R? I've taken a look at the documentation for download.file() but can't seem to find anything!

Comment: @Bazza i added request with user-agent in R, can you try it.

Comment: Hey @MeT thanks so much for this - exactly what I was looking for! Champion! I can't seem to 'upvote' your answer though.

Comment: @Bazza you welcome, don't upvote, just mark as valid answer for you, it will be ok. Thanks.